# Best place for getStoreConfig - block or model

Tags: magento

When creating a magento module i sometimes need store config values for use in a template file.  Where would be the best place for this - should I create a model or is a helper or block good enough?

I thinking in terms of best practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say a helper because it is accessible from everywhere. It wouldn't be hurtful to place in a block if it's only ever used in that block or it's template, although there is not much reason to create a block just for this when a helper will do.

A model should only be used to **model things**. As a rule of thumb I only use models for objects that might be used in a data structure, not as a convenience holder for functions.

Comment: There's not really a "right" answer here.  Like most things, it's consistency and what works best for your team that matter, BUT if you're trying to keep with the patterns employed by the core team, you'll want to drop config value reads into block methods.  Helpers are used from templates when there's a complicated value to be calculated from the system.

Answer (score 0):

Template should (whenever possible) get everything from block to keep it simple and little clogged... In the block you might call the helper for getting the config value if you think that will enhance reuse ability.